# Deploying an SSIS Package - TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which has 4 connections - a WebService, 2 SQL Server connections (across 2 domains), and 1 connection to an Oracle DB.

When the package is run from Visual Studio from a laptop, it runs OK. When I deploy it to the server, I'm getting 'TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified'.
Results of tnsping's:

**64 Bit Version of TNSPing**

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\BIN>tnsping myservice.name

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on 05-SEP-2
013 11:06:10

Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files: 
c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = ww.x.y.zzz)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = myservice.name))
)
OK (0 msec)
```

**32 Bit Version of TNSPing**

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN>tnsping myservice.name

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on 05-SEP-2
013 11:06:20

Copyright (c) 1997,  2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = ww.x.y.zzz)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = myservice.name))
    )
OK (0 msec)
```

Now a similar experiment using DTSWizard.exe.

Using Oracle Provider for OLE DB. Get same results with Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle.

Please see [this image](http://postimg.org/image/xjosn4uhx/) - I've not enough rep to post the image here..!

*(I've also tried using C:\PROGRAM~2\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe - no joy.)*

The laptop is 64-bit, and has Oracle 11.2.0 installed.
The server is 64-bit, and has Oracle 10.2.0 installed.

My understanding is that SQL Server Management Studio is 32-bit only - could this be where the problem lies?

Could anybody suggest where I could go from here? I've tried various connectors, none of which seem to make a blind bit of difference. The only other option I can think of is taking the drivers from the server, putting them on the Laptop, re-configuring the SSIS package to work with those, and then deploy it again -- but, I'm hoping to avoid that, if there's an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things:

1) make sure you set a windows system environment variable: TNS_ADMIN pointing to your TNS names file(restart sql server agent required)

2) look at your PATH and make sure the x64 client comes before the x32 client

3) if all else fails forgo the tns names files and use

[EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT)